# Is there a built-in login/logout endpoint in django REST?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-login

I want to make a login functionality on my app. For this I want a login endpoint.

Does django REST have a built-in endpoint or view to login?
(I will only be using it for `BasicAuthentication`).

I found many ways online but they were for `TokenAuth` but I just want `BasicAuth`

Comment: have you looked at this ? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication

Comment: I have read this but it does not mentions any build in endpoint for Basic Auth

Comment: And on the internet I have found 3rd parties but they only have endponts for token auth